# Perform a aggregate function inside a reduce function

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want to divide the `sumOfSquareOfLoadings` and `itemCount` in the same reduce function, where I am summing them and getting the count. But I am stuck in implementation because I have to perform the division to the aggregated value.

It seems I need to perform the division in another array? or is there any way I can perform the division in the same reduce function where I am aggregating other values?

```js
var newArray1 = [{
    ltd: "Cpt",
    stdSquare: "0.35",
    error: "0.65"
  },
  {
    ltd: "Cpt",
    stdSquare: "0.16",
    error: "0.84"
  },
  {
    ltd: "Ant",
    stdSquare: "0.21",
    error: "0.79"
  },
  {
    ltd: "Ant",
    stdSquare: "0.79",
    error: "0.21"
  }
];


var counts = newArray1.reduce((r, {
  ltd
}) => (r[ltd] = (r[ltd] || 0) + 1, r), {});


var newArray = [];
const result = [...newArray1.reduce((r, o) => {
  const key = o.ltd;
  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    sumOfSquareOfLoadings: 0,
    itemCount: counts[key],
    sumOferrors: 0,
    ave: 0
  });

  item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings += parseFloat(o.stdSquare);
  item.sumOferrors += parseFloat(o.error);
  item.ave = item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings / item.itemCount;
  
  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

I want to divide the value of `item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings` and the `item.itemCount` and store the result in `ave`.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "ltd": "Cpt",
    "error": "0.65",
    "sumOfSquareOfLoadings": 0.51,
    "itemCount": 2,
    "sumOferrors": 1.49,
    "ave": 0.25  /* sumOfSquareOfLoadings / itemCount */
  },
  {
    "ltd": "Ant",
    "error": "0.79",
    "sumOfSquareOfLoadings": 1,
    "itemCount": 2,
    "sumOferrors": 1,
    "ave": 0.5   /* sumOfSquareOfLoadings / itemCount */
  }
]
```

Comment: did you mean this `item.ave = item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings / item.itemCount;` ? if not please could you add expected result ..thanks

Comment: @Codenewbie yes, i mean the same the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of make an isolated array just for counting occurence, you could directly count that an accumulate the item count right in each reduce's iteratation

```
const item =
  r.get(key) ||
  Object.assign({}, o, {
    sumOfSquareOfLoadings: 0,
    itemCount: 0,
    sumOferrors: 0,
    ave: 0,
  })

item.itemCount += 1
```

**Full demo**

```js
var newArray1 = [
  {
    ltd: "Cpt",
    stdSquare: "0.35",
    error: "0.65",
  },
  {
    ltd: "Cpt",
    stdSquare: "0.16",
    error: "0.84",
  },
  {
    ltd: "Ant",
    stdSquare: "0.21",
    error: "0.79",
  },
  {
    ltd: "Ant",
    stdSquare: "0.79",
    error: "0.21",
  },
]

var newArray = []
const result = [
  ...newArray1
    .reduce((r, o) => {
      const key = o.ltd
      const item =
        r.get(key) ||
        Object.assign({}, o, {
          sumOfSquareOfLoadings: 0,
          itemCount: 0,
          sumOferrors: 0,
          ave: 0,
        })

      item.itemCount += 1
      item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings += parseFloat(o.stdSquare)
      item.sumOferrors += parseFloat(o.error)
      item.ave = item.sumOfSquareOfLoadings / item.itemCount

      return r.set(key, item)
    }, new Map())
    .values(),
]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,  just an additional bit, is there a way to create a new array by adding all those items with a key? there are unnecessary "stdSquare", and "error" in the results array.